# TextMeshPro Text Object is not visible in unity gameView

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Created a script that adds a textMeshPro text in a gameObject that is child of a canvas. But the text is not visible in the gameView playmode but it is visible on scene mode. The text size is made big and the position is Oth point.

[image]

Heres the code to make the textmesh object:

```
public GameObject g;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    TextMeshPro mText = g.AddComponent<TextMeshPro>();

    mText.autoSizeTextContainer = true;

    mText.text = "Hello there";

    // Set various font settings.
    mText.fontSize = 748;

    mText.alignment = TextAlignmentOptions.Center;


}
```

How can I make this visible to the camera? and Why its not rendering?

Comment: Can you verify in the scene view that the camera is actually looking in the direction of the textmesh?

Comment: thanks for feedback. After rotating camera I saw the object. If I add this textMesh pro object to the canvas all other texts are visible but this one, I have to point it to that direction. so, Can you mention What is the way to make the camera look at this object at vector zero?

Comment: Check the settings in your Canvas component. Is it world space? Screen space? It sounds like you want your UI to be rendered in screen space so set the Canvas' Render Mode to `Screen Space - Overlay`.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @Kwinten. it was already in SS - Overlay mode. I tested other modes. And only setting camera position manually made this text object visible. It would be nice, If that could render at the same position like default texts does.

Comment: I know this is quite an old question, but I encountered a similar problem recently, and I solved it using `TextMeshProUGUI`, instead of `TextMeshPro`. COuld it be the case?

Answer (score 5):

You can place a TextMeshPro GameObject in either world space (`Create > 3D Object > TextMeshPro - Text`) or UI space (`Create > UI > TextMeshPro - Text`). As a 3D Object it has a MeshRenderer so it is "in the world" and with the UI version it is "in the screen" using a Canvas.

FYI, your code worked for me, but I had to the `using TMPro;` directive at the top.

Comment: Derp I feel like an idiot for not realizing this straight away. When adding the text component via the editor I needed to use the version with the (UI) suffix appended to the name, not the other.

Answer (score 0):

probably your font size is so big and its cant contain your text area

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).